# How TO do @OneToMany RelationShip in jpa regarding with these two models

Tags: spring, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

There are two models `User` And `UserRole`  I want to do `@OneToMany` Mapping relationship regarding Id in User Model.

In User Model  ID Field =  userId in UserRole Model, On the basis of Id in User and userId in UserRole I have to do @OneToMany

**User Entity**

```
    package in.lifcare.account.user.model;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Transient;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
    import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming;

    import in.lifcare.account.facility.model.Facility;
    import lombok.Data;

    /**
     * @author Manoj-Mac
     *
     */
    @Entity
    @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
    @Data
    @Table(name = "pharmacist")
    public class User implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2605246920403237568L;

        @Id
        @Column(updatable = false)
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;

        @NotBlank
        private String firstName;

        private String lastName;

        @Column(updatable = false)
        @NotBlank
        private String mobile;

        @NotBlank
        private String email;

        @Column(updatable = false)
        @NotBlank
        private String userName;

        @NotBlank
        private String gender;

        @JsonIgnore
        private String relativeLocation;

        @JsonIgnore
        private String bucket;

        private Timestamp dateOfBirth;

        private String alternateNumber;

        private boolean isMobileVerified = false;

        private boolean isActive = false;

        private String verificationStatus = VERIFICATION_STATUS.UNVERIFIED;

        private String type;

        @CreationTimestamp
        @Column(updatable = false)
        private Timestamp createdAt;

        @UpdateTimestamp
        private Timestamp updatedAt; 

        @Transient
        private List<Facility> facilities;

        /*@Transient
        private List<UserRole> userRoles;
    */  
        @Transient
        private List<Long> facilityIds;

        @Transient
        private List<Long> roleIds;

        @Transient 
        private List<Role> roles;

        @Transient
        private List<String> permissions;

        public interface VERIFICATION_STATUS {
            String UNVERIFIED = "UNVERIFIED";
            String VERIFIED = "VERIFIED";
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(this.userName)) {
                this.userName = this.email;
            }
            return this.userName;
        }

        String callbackMobile;

        @OneToMany
        //@JoinTable(name = "user_role")
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        List<UserRole> userRoles;

        @OneToMany
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
        List<UserFacility> userFacilities;
    }
```

**UserRole Entity**

```
    package in.lifcare.account.user.model;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming;

    import lombok.Data;

    /**
     * @author Manoj-Mac
     *
     */
    @Data
    @Entity
    @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
    @Table(name = "user_role")
    public class UserRole implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2790994797966605979L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column
        private long Id;

        private long userId;

        private long roleId;

        //@ManyToOne
        private User user;

        @CreationTimestamp
        @Column(updatable = false)
        private Timestamp createdAt;

        @UpdateTimestamp
        private Timestamp updatedAt; 


    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem ? What have you tried ? What didn't worked ?